# Dynamically multiplying values inside loop using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have 1 fields of input type...and if i changed the value,it will multiplied the values on the loop..here is the example...

```
<input type='number' id='values' name='values' onkeyup='multiplied()'>
<?php 
   foreach($data as $value)
   {
     $no = 1;
     echo "<input type='number' class='form-control value' id='value' name='value' readonly value=".$value['value'].">";
     echo "<input type='number' class='form-control' id='total' name='total' readonly >";
     $no++;
   }

?>

function multiplied()
{
  var values = $('#values').val();
  var value = $('.value').val();
  total = values * value;
  $('#total').val(total)
}
```

how do i multiplied values dynamically when i change the values of ***id='values'***
Thank you,any helps will be appriciated

Comment: It would be useful and easier to help if you'd posted the generated HTML as opposed to PHP!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery `on` function.

```
$(document).on('change', '#values', function() {
        var values = $("#values").val();            
        $(".value").each(function(index, element){
            values *= element.value;                 
            $(this).next('input#total').val(values);
        });
});
```

Comment: Wrapping `this` back into a jQuery constructor just to get a value? Use `this.value` instead.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I've edited my code, is that you meant ? I could shorten my code by one line.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use same id multiple times. Use class instead. Also you have to loop through element when you have to change value

change

```
echo "<input type='number' class='form-control' id='total' name='total' readonly >";
```

to

```
echo "<input type='number' class='form-control total' name='total' readonly >";
```

And in script

```
<script>
function multiplied()
{
  var values = $('#values').val();
  $( ".value" ).each(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      total = values * value;
      $(this).next('input').val(total);
});

}
</script>
```

Also make sure you `total` input field is exactly next after `value` input field

OR you can also use `nextAll` with class name if `total` input field is not exactly next after `value` input field

```
<script>
function multiplied()
{
  var values = $('#values').val();
  $( ".value" ).each(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      total = values * value;
      $(this).nextAll('.total').val(total);
});

}
</script>
```